# Cannot compile a java library with Gradle, works with the IDE

Tags: java, gradle

I’m running into a weird problem when I try to build my [project](https://github.com/vinaysshenoy/types) via Gradle.

The build works fine when I import the project into IntelliJ and build/run tests via the IDE. However, if I run `./gradlew test`, the build fails and it’s unable to resolve symbols in the JDK (like `GenericArrayType`).

If I delegate IntelliJ’s build/run actions to Gradle, I see the same problems in my IDE as well, so something seems to be up with my Gradle build, and I can’t figure out what. Other projects work fine, so it seems to be a problem with this specific project.

I have tried this on different machines (one running Ubuntu and the other running macOS) as well as different Gradle versions (`4.10.2`, `5.1.1`), but the problem persists. I copied and pasted the source code to another project that already works perfectly fine, and then it started failing with the same errors as well, when I ran the unit tests.

Can someone help me figure out what’s going wrong here?

Here's what my `settings.gradle` looks like:

```
rootProject.name = 'types'
```

And `build.gradle`:

```
group 'com.vinaysshenoy'
version '1.0.0'

buildscript {
  ext.junit_version = '4.12'
  ext.assertj_version = '3.11.1'
  ext.jsr305_version = '3.0.2'

  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
}

apply plugin: 'java-library'

java {
  sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation "com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:$jsr305_version"
  testImplementation "junit:junit:$junit_version"
  testImplementation "org.assertj:assertj-core:$assertj_version"
}
```

Here's what I see when I run it via the command line:

```
      public static final class GenericArrayTypeImpl implements GenericArrayType {
                                                                ^
      symbol:   class GenericArrayType
      location: class Util
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/util/Util.java:230: error: cannot find symbol
      public static final class ParameterizedTypeImpl implements ParameterizedType {
                                                                 ^
      symbol:   class ParameterizedType
      location: class Util
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/util/Util.java:340: error: cannot find symbol
      public static final class WildcardTypeImpl implements WildcardType {
                                                            ^
      symbol:   class WildcardType
      location: class Util
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/Types.java:54: error: incompatible types: ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be converted to ParameterizedType
        return new ParameterizedTypeImpl(null, rawType, typeArguments);
               ^
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/Types.java:63: error: incompatible types: ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be converted to ParameterizedType
        return new ParameterizedTypeImpl(ownerType, rawType, typeArguments);
               ^
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/Types.java:68: error: incompatible types: GenericArrayTypeImpl cannot be converted to GenericArrayType
        return new GenericArrayTypeImpl(componentType);
               ^
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/Types.java:78: error: incompatible types: WildcardTypeImpl cannot be converted to WildcardType
        return new WildcardTypeImpl(new Type[] { bound }, EMPTY_TYPE_ARRAY);
               ^
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/Types.java:86: error: incompatible types: WildcardTypeImpl cannot be converted to WildcardType
        return new WildcardTypeImpl(new Type[] { Object.class }, new Type[] { bound });
               ^
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/Types.java:153: error: incompatible types: ParameterizedType cannot be converted to ParameterizedTypeImpl
          Type[] aTypeArguments = pa instanceof ParameterizedTypeImpl
                                  ^
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/Types.java:154: error: incompatible types: ParameterizedType cannot be converted to ParameterizedTypeImpl
              ? ((ParameterizedTypeImpl) pa).typeArguments
                                         ^
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/Types.java:156: error: incompatible types: ParameterizedType cannot be converted to ParameterizedTypeImpl
          Type[] bTypeArguments = pb instanceof ParameterizedTypeImpl
                                  ^
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/Types.java:157: error: incompatible types: ParameterizedType cannot be converted to ParameterizedTypeImpl
              ? ((ParameterizedTypeImpl) pb).typeArguments
                                         ^
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/util/Util.java:52: error: incompatible types: bad type in conditional expression
          return c.isArray() ? new GenericArrayTypeImpl(canonicalize(c.getComponentType())) : c;
                               ^
        GenericArrayTypeImpl cannot be converted to Type
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/util/Util.java:55: error: incompatible types: Type cannot be converted to ParameterizedTypeImpl
          if (type instanceof ParameterizedTypeImpl) { return type; }
              ^
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/util/Util.java:57: error: incompatible types: ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be converted to Type
          return new ParameterizedTypeImpl(p.getOwnerType(),
                 ^
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/util/Util.java:61: error: incompatible types: Type cannot be converted to GenericArrayTypeImpl
          if (type instanceof GenericArrayTypeImpl) { return type; }
              ^
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/util/Util.java:63: error: incompatible types: GenericArrayTypeImpl cannot be converted to Type
          return new GenericArrayTypeImpl(g.getGenericComponentType());
                 ^
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/util/Util.java:66: error: incompatible types: Type cannot be converted to WildcardTypeImpl
          if (type instanceof WildcardTypeImpl) { return type; }
              ^
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/util/Util.java:68: error: incompatible types: WildcardTypeImpl cannot be converted to Type
          return new WildcardTypeImpl(w.getUpperBounds(), w.getLowerBounds());
                 ^
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/util/Util.java:118: error: incompatible types: bad type in conditional expression
                ? new ParameterizedTypeImpl(newOwnerType, original.getRawType(), args)
                  ^
        ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be converted to Type
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/util/Util.java:260: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/util/Util.java:265: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/util/Util.java:270: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/util/Util.java:279: error: incompatible types: ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be converted to Type
              && Types.equals(this, (ParameterizedType) other);
                              ^
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/util/Util.java:313: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/util/Util.java:321: error: incompatible types: GenericArrayTypeImpl cannot be converted to Type
              && Types.equals(this, (GenericArrayType) o);
                              ^
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/util/Util.java:363: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/util/Util.java:368: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
    /Users/vinay/Dev/IdeaProjects/types/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/util/Util.java:376: error: incompatible types: WildcardTypeImpl cannot be converted to Type
              && Types.equals(this, (WildcardType) other);
                          ^
```

Comment: Downloading your project and running it as is with `./gradlew`, both `./gradlew build` and `./gradlew test` run successfully. (just to let you know that at another machine it seems to work correctly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

@Zgurskyi’s answer is a good workaround, however, I believe it only cures the symptom of the actual problem (see below). Here’s another, IMHO cleaner way to fix the underlying issue: make the imports of the nested types of `com.vinaysshenoy.types.util.Util` from `com.vinaysshenoy.types.Types` **non-static**:

```
diff --git a/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/Types.java b/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/Types.java
index e3a44d8..92ac237 100644
--- a/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/Types.java
+++ b/src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/Types.java
@@ -17,9 +17,9 @@ package com.vinaysshenoy.types;


 import static com.vinaysshenoy.types.util.Util.EMPTY_TYPE_ARRAY;
-import static com.vinaysshenoy.types.util.Util.GenericArrayTypeImpl;
-import static com.vinaysshenoy.types.util.Util.ParameterizedTypeImpl;
-import static com.vinaysshenoy.types.util.Util.WildcardTypeImpl;
+import com.vinaysshenoy.types.util.Util.GenericArrayTypeImpl;
+import com.vinaysshenoy.types.util.Util.ParameterizedTypeImpl;
+import com.vinaysshenoy.types.util.Util.WildcardTypeImpl;
 import static com.vinaysshenoy.types.util.Util.getGenericSupertype;
 import static com.vinaysshenoy.types.util.Util.resolve;
```

(BTW, other than @Zgurskyi I can also reproduce this with a manual `javac` call. I only have one JDK installed; maybe @Zgurskyi’s `javac` on the command line is not from the same JDK that Gradle uses.)

### Actual Problem

You statically import nested classes (not just class *members*), although this should never be necessary. I’m actually surprised that this seems to usually work, but apparently some Java compilers at least choke on it under certain circumstances.

In your case, the Java compiler used by Gradle couldn’t correctly resolve the imports in the following scenario (only a rough, not very technical description of what the compiler does):

1. when processing `com.vinaysshenoy.types.util.Util`, the compiler finds a static import of `com.vinaysshenoy.types.Types.arrayOf`, so the compiler looks at the `com.vinaysshenoy.types.Types` class.
2. `com.vinaysshenoy.types.Types` has a static import of `com.vinaysshenoy.types.util.Util.GenericArrayTypeImpl`, so the compiler looks at the nested `GenericArrayTypeImpl` class.
3. `com.vinaysshenoy.types.util.Util.GenericArrayTypeImpl` uses (`java.lang.reflect.`)`GenericArrayType`, however, the import for that type was not yet processed at this point which leads to the “cannot find symbol” error.

Arguably, it could also be considered to be a JDK bug that this works with some compilers but not with others.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed write-up! This stupefied me for a week! Weird that this isn't flagged as an error or something in the IDE.

Answer (score 3):

In order to build the project, **use fully qualified names** for implemented interfaces for static nested classes defined in `com.vinaysshenoy.types.util.Util`:

```
  public static final class ParameterizedTypeImpl implements java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType { ... }

  public static final class GenericArrayTypeImpl implements java.lang.reflect.GenericArrayType { ... }

  public static final class WildcardTypeImpl implements java.lang.reflect.WildcardType { ... }
```

Also, if you don't want to use fully qualified names, then just extract static nested classes to top level.

Notes:

1. The project compiles without errors, when JDK compiler is used:

```
javac -cp path_to_jsr305-3.0.2.jar -d bin src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/Types.java src/main/java/com/vinaysshenoy/types/util/Util.java
```

2. This problem seems to be dependent on platform. I've tried to build project on Windows 10/Oracle JDK 1.8.0_111 - and no issues were observed. However, the issue reproduced exactly as described on Ubuntu 16.04/Oracle JDK 1.8.0_201 & Ubuntu 16.04/OpenJDK 1.8.0_191.

Comment: i can confirm that by changing the final class declarations the build works fine on mac too.

Comment: Whoa, I didn't know this could be a problem. I shall try this out in a few hours when I get back home from work and see!

Comment: This fixed the problem, but @chriki has a far more detailed answer, so I am going to award the bounty to them. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I checked out your project, and could successfully build it with `gradlew clean build`.

I assume that **gradle can't find the JDK installation**, due to

- the JDK not being installed (IDEs often come with their own bundled installation), or
- the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable not being properly set (set and point it to your JDK installation directory).

Comment: This was something that I thought of, and running `echo $JAVA_HOME` does output a path: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home`.

Comment: Yes. It prints `java version "1.8.0_181"` as expected.

Comment: The 'java' command is part of the JRE and does not indicate any presence of the JDK. `javac -version` on the other hand would at least confirm the presence of the JDK, but not if JAVA_HOME was properly set. @VinaySShenoy: can you check for the presence of the 'bin' and 'lib' folders within the path you posted in the commend, and also check if the javac executable is present in the 'bin' folder?

Comment: Yes, the `javac` command is present and prints `javac 1.8.0_181` too. The `bin` and `lib` folders are present as well.

Comment: Assuming the Java and Gradle installations are ok, let's assume that there is really something wrong with the project or code. You said you tried building the project on different machines - was that the same state that is currently published on GitHub? That leaves the question why it builds on my machine without issues. Are there any local changes which you haven't pushed?

Comment: Yes, everything is pushed. What's weird is that if I copy the sources to another project that is working perfectly fine and I try to build it, I see the same problem happening again.

Comment: I checked this project and gradlew test successfully work for me, mb try to install gradle on your machine. Also check gradle settings in intellij mb offline work checked for gralde.

Comment: @ksandr I am using the gradle wrapper, there's no need to install gradle specifically. It's not just intellij, running it via the command line breaks too.

Answer (score 1):

after having built the project, I've come to a whole other conclusion: it seems the system-wide `JDK` has corrupted files - and that it works with the IDE, that is because it uses an embedded version.

in case Gradle cannot use that `JDK`, it can be defined in the `gradle.properties` file (the path to the IDE's embedded `JDK` should work, better than the one installed system-wide, as used by default):

```
# replace this path with the path to the IDE's embedded JDK:
org.gradle.java.home = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home
```

... and this should already make it build.